# MyToolkit for windows phone 7.x "Sorry we can't play this file on your phone" for VEVO videos

Tags: c#, xaml, youtube, windows-phone

I'm trying to upload videos directly from my application. I'm using SDK MyToolkit which is great, but has some bugs.

This is my source code:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (YouTube.CancelPlay())
                e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            YouTube.CancelPlay(); // used to reenable page

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);            
        }

        private void OnPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {

            YouTube.Play(id, true, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P, e =>
            {
                if (e != null)


      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        });
    }

    private void btnYoutube_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        YouTube.Play(id, true, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P, ex => 
        {
            if (ex != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("...");
            }
        });
    }
```

This code generates no error, but when going to open the video link the following message appears:

> "Sorry we can't play this file on your phone"

I am using the YoutubeButton in xaml:

```
<Controls:YouTubeButton x:Name="btnYoutube" Tap="btnYoutube_Tap" Height="269"/>
```

[MyToolkit Documentation](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28598#-%20Samples/SamplePhoneApp/Views/YouTubePage.xaml.cs)

---

> I found a possible cause of the problem. I checked other videos and
>   they run perfectly with this code. However the video channel VEVO can
>   not be used. Does anyone know any solution to the problem?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a YouTube restriction I'm afraid.  Not entirely sure how to unblock it but a fair amount of videos are tagged as HQ or have a "non-mobile" flag.
Certain channels also only allow desktop viewing and changing the browser version on your phone (mobile vs desktop) does not help.

Not even sure if it's possible from Windows Phone devices for uploaded videos.

One suggestion is to look at the YouTube developer pages to see if there are any tags you can set programatically while uploading.